# C# Get JObject inner token

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this Json structure:

```
{
  "rc": 1,
  "msg": 
  [
    {
      "msgId": "6661",
      "msgTxt": "Invalid Token"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get the 6661 Value? I've tried lots of paths, but it seems those two square brackets are making my day hard

Thanks

Comment: it is an array `msg[0].msgId`

Comment: It may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp/28123400#28123400

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `jdoc` is your parsed document, then:

```
var res = jdoc["msg"][0]["msgId"];
```

should do it (but real code should handle errors as well).

Answer (score 0):

Using JObject parser, you could use :

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(yourObjectJson);
var value = obj["msg"][0]["msgId"];
```